# PHP get contents of page using file_get_contents returns nothing

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch data from the roblox website using file_get_contents. I am trying to access the find a user page: http://www.roblox.com/search/users?keyword=

When I request the page I give 1 get parameter called username=[name]. However as soon as I try to load up the page no result is given back.

I tried file_get_contents, domdocument, curl. Nothing worked. I don't know what to do anymore.

```
<?php
    $User = $_GET["username"];
    $Result = file_get_contents("http://www.roblox.com/search/users?keyword=".$User);
    var_dump($Result);
?>
```

I'm not getting any errors. Just chrome connection timeout errors.

Comment: "no result is given back" - meaning you get a _blank_ page?

Comment: Exactly when I try to output the result nothing shows up.

Comment: is your 1 parameter _username_ or _keyword_? Because it looks like _keyword_.

Comment: I call to this php page using the parameter username. And I add that value to the roblox page as the parameter keyword: http://testformywebsites.site50.net/Processors/RobloxGetUsers.php?username=

Comment: It works.  Look more closely at the response.  It's not empty.  Looks like some possible obfuscation on their end.  Love me some ASCII art :)  They maybe offer an API?  see: https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313380-Account-Security-Theft-Keeping-your-Account-Safe-

Comment: I agree with @ficuscr, I just tested it and it appears to work just fine.

Comment: Try `var_dump(htmlentities($Result));`. The result is HTML, so when you dump it on your web page the browser interprets the HTML.

Comment: Could it just be my crappy internet?

Comment: This is all I'm getting on my end: http://prntscr.com/8hukv5

Comment: @ficuscr They do have an online web API however it's very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with firebug (dev tools) open:  http://codepad.viper-7.com/fbEOPp

Would have to dig in a bit more to see what obfuscation is happening.  At *least* one redirect in there.  Might be looking at the `agent` or using other means.  Maybe look if they offer an API or take a look at their site terms and conditions.

Source shows...

```
      _______      _________      _____       ______     _
     / _____ \    |____ ____|    / ___ \     | ____ \   | |
    / /     \_\       | |       / /   \ \    | |   \ \  | |
    | |               | |      / /     \ \   | |   | |  | |
    \ \______         | |      | |     | |   | |___/ /  | |
     \______ \        | |      | |     | |   |  ____/   | |
            \ \       | |      | |     | |   | |        | |
     _      | |       | |      \ \     / /   | |        |_|
    \ \_____/ /       | |       \ \___/ /    | |         _
     \_______/        |_|        \_____/     |_|        |_|

     Keep your account safe! Do not paste any text here.

     If someone is asking you to paste text here then you're 
     giving someone access to your account, your gear, and
     your ROBUX.

     To learn more about keeping your account safe you can go to

     https://en.help.roblox.com/hc/en-us/articles/203313380-Account-Security-Theft-Keeping-your-Account-Safe-
```

(hmm, seems they spit that out always with every request - though it was specific to how we were trying things)

Still, might be the site does not like you scraping their (your?) content and is actively trying to thwart your attempts.

Here is a screenshot of what I get from file_get_contents after a 15 second wait...

[image]

Comment: Did you open firefox or chrome dev tools like I specified?  Also looks like a couple hops in there - takes a minute.  Will see output on console.  Anyway, they really don't want you doing that it seems like.

Comment: I'm not getting anything in chrome developer tools. Only this: /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details. Well it's not that they don't want me to access it. Because when I try to fetch the main site I have no problems.

Comment: I got the exact same thing on codeviper aswell. However my own site can't manage it? Could it be something inside my server that's blocking it?

Comment: Could be many things, they might be watching IPs, might be the agent (which would differ from server/php version etc) they see.  Might be they want to prevent scraping, might be part of some XSS prevention scheme.  Would suggest trying cURL if you really want to get around whatever they are doing - can adjust the agent string sent, handle redirects better, use a cookie, etc...

Comment: Wait, just found out I cannot access a single page of my website. My host might have maintenance or something. Let me quickly try it on my second hosting service.

Comment: My original host is dead apparently. Tried it on my second host and it worked fine. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 1):

> Just chrome connection timeout errors.

That suggests that your php script isn't failing but stalling. Could be the http request; so, let's try it with a shorter timeout:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(-1);

$User = $_GET["username"];
$ctx  = stream_context_create(array('http'=>array(
    'timeout'=>3.0
)));

$Result = file_get_contents(
    "http://www.roblox.com/search/users?keyword=".$User,
    false,
    $ctx
);
var_dump($Result);
?>
```

Comment: Same result it still gives a chrome timeout

Comment: Has to do with how file_get_contents handles certain redirects I think.  Would suggest use of cURL here.